# problems when converting class based to function based component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i have converted my class  based component as below and i have converted to function based in the below but i am not sure about if my variables are are defined correctly and my function based component is running as a infinite loop can someone guide me right direction?

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack,
  mediaDevices,
  registerGlobals,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';

import io from 'socket.io-client';

const dimensions = Dimensions.get('window');

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      localStream: null,
      remoteStream: null,
    };

    this.sdp;
    this.socket = null;
    this.candidates = [];
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.socket = io.connect('https://daae-171-61-.ngrok.io/webrtcPeer', {
      path: '/io/webrtc',
      query: {},
    });

    this.socket.on('connection-success', (success) => {
      console.log(success);
    });

    this.socket.on('offerOrAnswer', (sdp) => {
      this.sdp = JSON.stringify(sdp);

      // set sdp as remote description
      this.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));
    });

    this.socket.on('candidate', (candidate) => {
      // console.log('From Peer... ', JSON.stringify(candidate))
      // this.candidates = [...this.candidates, candidate]
      this.pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
    });

    const pc_config = {
      iceServers: [
        // {
        //   urls: 'stun:[STUN_IP]:[PORT]',
        //   'credentials': '[YOR CREDENTIALS]',
        //   'username': '[USERNAME]'
        // },
        {
          urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
        },
      ],
    };

    this.pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);

    this.pc.onicecandidate = (e) => {
      // send the candidates to the remote peer
      // see addCandidate below to be triggered on the remote peer
      if (e.candidate) {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(e.candidate))
        this.sendToPeer('candidate', e.candidate);
      }
    };

    // triggered when there is a change in connection state
    this.pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    };

    this.pc.onaddstream = (e) => {
      debugger;
      // this.remoteVideoref.current.srcObject = e.streams[0]
      this.setState({
        remoteStream: e.stream,
      });
    };

    const success = (stream) => {
      console.log(stream.toURL());
      this.setState({
        localStream: stream,
      });
      this.pc.addStream(stream);
    };

    const failure = (e) => {
      console.log('getUserMedia Error: ', e);
    };

    let isFront = true;
    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((sourceInfos) => {
      console.log(sourceInfos);
      let videoSourceId;
      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (
          sourceInfo.kind == 'videoinput' &&
          sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? 'front' : 'environment')
        ) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
        }
      }

      const constraints = {
        audio: true,
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
            minHeight: 300,
            minFrameRate: 30,
          },
          facingMode: isFront ? 'user' : 'environment',
          optional: videoSourceId ? [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] : [],
        },
      };

      mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(success).catch(failure);
    });
  };
  sendToPeer = (messageType, payload) => {
    this.socket.emit(messageType, {
      socketID: this.socket.id,
      payload,
    });
  };

  createOffer = () => {
    console.log('Offer');

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer
    // initiates the creation of SDP
    this.pc.createOffer({offerToReceiveVideo: 1}).then((sdp) => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp))

      // set offer sdp as local description
      this.pc.setLocalDescription(sdp);

      this.sendToPeer('offerOrAnswer', sdp);
    });
  };

  createAnswer = () => {
    console.log('Answer');
    this.pc.createAnswer({offerToReceiveVideo: 1}).then((sdp) => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp))

      // set answer sdp as local description
      this.pc.setLocalDescription(sdp);

      this.sendToPeer('offerOrAnswer', sdp);
    });
  };

  setRemoteDescription = () => {
    // retrieve and parse the SDP copied from the remote peer
    const desc = JSON.parse(this.sdp);

    // set sdp as remote description
    this.pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(desc));
  };

  addCandidate = () => {
    // retrieve and parse the Candidate copied from the remote peer
    // const candidate = JSON.parse(this.textref.value)
    // console.log('Adding candidate:', candidate)

    // add the candidate to the peer connection
    // this.pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))

    this.candidates.forEach((candidate) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(candidate));
      this.pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {localStream, remoteStream} = this.state;

    const remoteVideo = remoteStream ? (
      <RTCView
        key={2}
        mirror={true}
        style={{...styles.rtcViewRemote}}
        objectFit="contain"
        streamURL={remoteStream && remoteStream.toURL()}
      />
    ) : (
      <View style={{padding: 15}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 22, textAlign: 'center', color: 'white'}}>
          Waiting for Peer connection ...
        </Text>
      </View>
    );

    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle={'dark-content'} />
        <View style={{...styles.buttonsContainer}}>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.createOffer}>
              <View style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={{...styles.textContent}}>Call</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.createAnswer}>
              <View style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={{...styles.textContent}}>Answer</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={{...styles.videosContainer}}>
          <View
            style={{
              position: 'absolute',
              zIndex: 1,
              bottom: 10,
              right: 10,
              width: 100,
              height: 200,
              backgroundColor: 'black', //width: '100%', height: '100%'
            }}>
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => localStream._tracks[1]._switchCamera()}>
                <View>
                  <RTCView
                    key={1}
                    zOrder={0}
                    objectFit="cover"
                    style={{...styles.rtcView}}
                    streamURL={localStream && localStream.toURL()}
                  />
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <ScrollView style={{...styles.scrollView}}>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                width: '100%',
                backgroundColor: 'black',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
              }}>
              {remoteVideo}
            </View>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  button: {
    margin: 5,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  textContent: {
    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  videosContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  rtcView: {
    width: 100, //dimensions.width,
    height: 200, //dimensions.height / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
    // flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'teal',
    padding: 15,
  },
  rtcViewRemote: {
    width: dimensions.width - 30,
    height: 200, //dimensions.height / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
});

export default App;
```

to the following function based code, but here i have issues it goes into infinite loop can someone guide as to where i am going wrong and are  variables declared correctly.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack,
  mediaDevices,
  registerGlobals,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';

import io from 'socket.io-client';

const dimensions = Dimensions.get('window');

const App = () => {
  const [localStream, setlocalStream] = useState(null);
  const [remoteStream, setremoteStream] = useState(null);

  var sdp;
  var socket = null;
  var candidates = [];

  const pc_config = {
    iceServers: [
      // {
      //   urls: 'stun:[STUN_IP]:[PORT]',
      //   'credentials': '[YOR CREDENTIALS]',
      //   'username': '[USERNAME]'
      // },
      {
        urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
      },
    ],
  };

  var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket = io.connect('https://daae-171-61-95-23.ngrok.io/webrtcPeer', {
      path: '/io/webrtc',
      query: {},
    });

    socket.on('connection-success', success => {
      console.log(success);
    });

    socket.on('offerOrAnswer', sdp => {
      sdp = JSON.stringify(sdp);

      // set sdp as remote description
      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));
    });

    socket.on('candidate', candidate => {
      // console.log('From Peer... ', JSON.stringify(candidate))
      // this.candidates = [...this.candidates, candidate]
      pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
    });

    pc.onicecandidate = e => {
      // send the candidates to the remote peer
      // see addCandidate below to be triggered on the remote peer
      if (e.candidate) {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(e.candidate))
        sendToPeer('candidate', e.candidate);
      }
    };

    // triggered when there is a change in connection state
    pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => {
      console.log(e);
    };

    pc.onaddstream = e => {
      debugger;
      // this.remoteVideoref.current.srcObject = e.streams[0]
      setremoteStream(e.stream);
    };

    const success = stream => {
      console.log(stream.toURL());
      setlocalStream(stream);

      pc.addStream(stream);
    };

    const failure = e => {
      console.log('getUserMedia Error: ', e);
    };

    let isFront = true;
    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(sourceInfos => {
      console.log(sourceInfos);
      let videoSourceId;
      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (
          sourceInfo.kind == 'videoinput' &&
          sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? 'front' : 'environment')
        ) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
        }
      }

      const constraints = {
        audio: true,
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
            minHeight: 300,
            minFrameRate: 30,
          },
          facingMode: isFront ? 'user' : 'environment',
          optional: videoSourceId ? [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] : [],
        },
      };

      mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(success).catch(failure);
    });
  }, []);

  const sendToPeer = (messageType, payload) => {
    socket.emit(messageType, {
      socketID: socket.id,
      payload,
    });
  };

  const createOffer = () => {
    console.log('Offer');

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer
    // initiates the creation of SDP
    pc.createOffer({offerToReceiveVideo: 1}).then(sdp => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp))

      // set offer sdp as local description
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp);

      sendToPeer('offerOrAnswer', sdp);
    });
  };

  const createAnswer = () => {
    console.log('Answer');
    pc.createAnswer({offerToReceiveVideo: 1}).then(sdp => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp))

      // set answer sdp as local description
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp);

      sendToPeer('offerOrAnswer', sdp);
    });
  };

  setRemoteDescription = () => {
    // retrieve and parse the SDP copied from the remote peer
    const desc = JSON.parse(sdp);

    // set sdp as remote description
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(desc));
  };

  addCandidate = () => {
    // retrieve and parse the Candidate copied from the remote peer
    // const candidate = JSON.parse(this.textref.value)
    // console.log('Adding candidate:', candidate)

    // add the candidate to the peer connection
    // this.pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))

    candidates.forEach(candidate => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(candidate));
      pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
    });
  };

  const remoteVideo = remoteStream ? (
    <RTCView
      key={2}
      mirror={true}
      style={{...styles.rtcViewRemote}}
      objectFit="contain"
      streamURL={remoteStream && remoteStream.toURL()}
    />
  ) : (
    <View style={{padding: 15}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 22, textAlign: 'center', color: 'white'}}>
        Waiting for Peer connection ...
      </Text>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle={'dark-content'} />
      <View style={{...styles.buttonsContainer}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={createOffer}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={{...styles.textContent}}>Call</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={createAnswer}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={{...styles.textContent}}>Answer</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{...styles.videosContainer}}>
        <View
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            zIndex: 1,
            bottom: 10,
            right: 10,
            width: 100,
            height: 200,
            backgroundColor: 'black', //width: '100%', height: '100%'
          }}>
          <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => localStream._tracks[1]._switchCamera()}>
              <View>
                <RTCView
                  key={1}
                  zOrder={0}
                  objectFit="cover"
                  style={{...styles.rtcView}}
                  streamURL={localStream && localStream.toURL()}
                />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={{...styles.scrollView}}>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              width: '100%',
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}>
            {remoteVideo}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  button: {
    margin: 5,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  textContent: {
    fontFamily: 'Avenir',
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  videosContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  rtcView: {
    width: 100, //dimensions.width,
    height: 200, //dimensions.height / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
    // flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'teal',
    padding: 15,
  },
  rtcViewRemote: {
    width: dimensions.width - 30,
    height: 200, //dimensions.height / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
});

export default App;
```

------     in my react js   ------    the line console.log(localStream) seems to be rerendering (this line is before return statement in react js code)

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

import io from "socket.io-client";

import Video from "./Components/Video";

const pc_config = {
  iceServers: [
    // {
    //   urls: 'stun:[STUN_IP]:[PORT]',
    //   'credentials': '[YOR CREDENTIALS]',
    //   'username': '[USERNAME]'
    // },
    {
      urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
    },
  ],
};

const App = () => {
  const [localStream, setlocalStream] = useState(null);
  // https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
  // const localVideoref = React.createRef();
  const remoteVideoref = React.createRef();
  const socket = useRef(
    io.connect("https://3eae-171-61-95-23.ngrok.io/webrtcPeer", {
      path: "/io/webrtc",
      query: {},
    })
  );
  var textref;
  var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);
  const candidates = useRef([]);
  //var socket = null;
  // var candidates = [];
  // var textref;

  //const pc_config = null;

  //var pc = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection
  // create an instance of RTCPeerConnection

  useEffect(() => {
    // socket = io.connect("https://3eae-171-61-95-23.ngrok.io/webrtcPeer", {
    //   path: "/io/webrtc",
    //   query: {},
    // });

    // connection success event handler
    socket.current.on("connection-success", (success) => {
      console.log("connection-success---->>>>", success);
    });

    // offerOrAnswer event handler
    socket.current.on("offerOrAnswer", (sdp) => {
      textref.value = JSON.stringify(sdp);

      // set sdp as remote description
      pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));
    });

    // candidate event handler
    socket.current.on("candidate", (candidate) => {
      // console.log('From Peer... ', JSON.stringify(candidate))
      // when we recieve ice candidates add it to an array

      // candidates = [...candidates, candidate];

      pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
    });

    // triggered when a new candidate is returned
    pc.onicecandidate = (e) => {
      // send the candidates to the remote peer
      // see addCandidate below to be triggered on the remote peer
      if (e.candidate) {
        console.log("e.candidate---->", JSON.stringify(e.candidate));
        sendToPeer("candidate", e.candidate);
      }
    };

    // triggered when there is a change in connection state
    pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    };

    // triggered when a stream is added to pc, see below - this.pc.addStream(stream)
    // this.pc.onaddstream = (e) => {
    //   this.remoteVideoref.current.srcObject = e.stream
    // }

    pc.ontrack = (e) => {
      debugger;
      remoteVideoref.current.srcObject = e.streams[0];
    };

    // called when getUserMedia() successfully returns - see below
    // getUserMedia() returns a MediaStream object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream)
    const success = (stream) => {
      window.localStream = stream;
      //  localVideoref.current.srcObject = stream;
      pc.addStream(stream);
      setlocalStream(stream);
    };

    // called when getUserMedia() fails - see below
    const failure = (e) => {
      console.log("getUserMedia Error: ", e);
    };

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
    // see the above link for more constraint options
    const constraints = {
      audio: false,
      video: true,
      // video: {
      //   width: 1280,
      //   height: 720
      // },
      // video: {
      //   width: { min: 1280 },
      // }
    };

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(success)
      .catch(failure);
  });

  /* ACTION METHODS FROM THE BUTTONS ON SCREEN */

  const sendToPeer = (messageType, payload) => {
    socket.current.emit(messageType, {
      socketID: socket.id,
      payload,
    });
  };

  const createOffer = () => {
    console.log("Offer");

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer
    // initiates the creation of SDP
    pc.createOffer({ offerToReceiveVideo: 1 }).then((sdp) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp));

      // set offer sdp as local description
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp);
      sendToPeer("offerOrAnswer", sdp);
    });
  };

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createAnswer
  // creates an SDP answer to an offer received from remote peer
  const createAnswer = () => {
    console.log("Answer");
    pc.createAnswer({ offerToReceiveVideo: 1 }).then((sdp) => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp));

      // set answer sdp as local description
      pc.setLocalDescription(sdp);
      sendToPeer("offerOrAnswer", sdp);
    });
  };

  const setRemoteDescription = () => {
    // retrieve and parse the SDP copied from the remote peer
    // console.log("pasted value", textref.value);
    const desc = JSON.parse(textref.value);

    // set sdp as remote description
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(desc));
  };

  const addCandidate = () => {
    // retrieve and parse the Candidate copied from the remote peer
    // const candidate = JSON.parse(textref.value);
    // console.log("Adding candidate:", candidate);
    // add the candidate to the peer connection
    //  pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));

    candidates.forEach((candidate) => {
      console.log("candidate---->", JSON.stringify(candidate));
      pc.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
    });
  };
  console.log("local stream---->", localStream);
  return (
    <div>
      <Video
        style={{
          zIndex: 2,
          position: "fixed",
          right: 0,
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          margin: 5,
          backgroundColor: "black",
        }}
        // ref={localVideoref}
        videoStream={localStream}
        autoPlay
        muted
      ></Video>
      <Video
        style={{
          zIndex: 1,
          position: "fixed",
          bottom: 0,
          minWidth: "100%",
          minHeight: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "black",
        }}
        ref={remoteVideoref}
        autoPlay
      ></Video>
      <br />

      <div style={{ zIndex: 1, position: "fixed" }}>
        <button onClick={createOffer}>Offer</button>
        <button onClick={createAnswer}>Answer</button>

        <br />
        <textarea
          style={{ width: 450, height: 40 }}
          ref={(ref) => {
            textref = ref;
          }}
        />
      </div>
      {/* <br />
      <button onClick={setRemoteDescription}>Set Remote Desc</button>
      <button onClick={addCandidate}>Add Candidate</button> */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: The variables `sdp`, `candidates` and `pc` gets re-initialied on every re-render. Create a  `ref` variable to store them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Dimensions,
} from "react-native";

import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCIceCandidate,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  MediaStream,
  MediaStreamTrack,
  mediaDevices,
  registerGlobals,
} from "react-native-webrtc";

import io from "socket.io-client";

const dimensions = Dimensions.get("window");

const pc_config = {
  iceServers: [
    // {
    //   urls: 'stun:[STUN_IP]:[PORT]',
    //   'credentials': '[YOR CREDENTIALS]',
    //   'username': '[USERNAME]'
    // },
    {
      urls: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302",
    },
  ],
};

function App(props) {
  const [localStream, SetlocalStream] = useState(null);
  const [remoteStream, SetremoteStream] = useState(null);
  const socket = useRef(
    io.connect("https://daae-171-61-.ngrok.io/webrtcPeer", {
      path: "/io/webrtc",
      query: {},
    })
  );
  const sdp = useRef(null);
  const pc = useRef(new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config));
  const candidates = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.current.on("connection-success", (success) => {
      console.log(success);
    });

    socket.current.on("offerOrAnswer", (sdp) => {
      sdp.current = JSON.stringify(sdp);

      // set sdp as remote description
      pc.current.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(sdp));
    });

    socket.current.on("candidate", (candidate) => {
      // console.log('From Peer... ', JSON.stringify(candidate))
      // candidates.current = [...candidates.current, candidate]
      pc.current.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
    });

    pc.current = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);

    pc.current.onicecandidate = (e) => {
      // send the candidates to the remote peer
      // see addCandidate below to be triggered on the remote peer
      if (e.candidate) {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(e.candidate))
        sendToPeer("candidate", e.candidate);
      }
    };

    // triggered when there is a change in connection state
    pc.current.oniceconnectionstatechange = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    };

    pc.current.onaddstream = (e) => {
      debugger;
      // this.remoteVideoref.current.srcObject = e.streams[0]
      SetremoteStream(e.stream);
    };

    const success = (stream) => {
      console.log(stream.toURL());
      SetlocalStream(stream);
      pc.current.addStream(stream);
    };

    const failure = (e) => {
      console.log("getUserMedia Error: ", e);
    };

    let isFront = true;
    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((sourceInfos) => {
      console.log(sourceInfos);
      let videoSourceId;
      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (
          sourceInfo.kind == "videoinput" &&
          sourceInfo.facing == (isFront ? "front" : "environment")
        ) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
        }
      }

      const constraints = {
        audio: true,
        video: {
          mandatory: {
            minWidth: 500, // Provide your own width, height and frame rate here
            minHeight: 300,
            minFrameRate: 30,
          },
          facingMode: isFront ? "user" : "environment",
          optional: videoSourceId ? [{ sourceId: videoSourceId }] : [],
        },
      };

      mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(success).catch(failure);
    });
  }, []);

  const sendToPeer = (messageType, payload) => {
    socket.current.emit(messageType, {
      socketID: socket.current.id,
      payload,
    });
  };

  const createOffer = () => {
    console.log("Offer");

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer
    // initiates the creation of SDP
    pc.current.createOffer({ offerToReceiveVideo: 1 }).then((sdp) => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp))

      // set offer sdp as local description
      pc.current.setLocalDescription(sdp);

      sendToPeer("offerOrAnswer", sdp);
    });
  };

  const createAnswer = () => {
    console.log("Answer");
    pc.current.createAnswer({ offerToReceiveVideo: 1 }).then((sdp) => {
      // console.log(JSON.stringify(sdp))

      // set answer sdp as local description
      pc.current.setLocalDescription(sdp);

      sendToPeer("offerOrAnswer", sdp);
    });
  };

  const setRemoteDescription = () => {
    // retrieve and parse the SDP copied from the remote peer
    const desc = JSON.parse(sdp.current);

    // set sdp as remote description
    pc.current.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(desc));
  };

  const addCandidate = () => {
    // retrieve and parse the Candidate copied from the remote peer
    // const candidate = JSON.parse(this.textref.value)
    // console.log('Adding candidate:', candidate)

    // add the candidate to the peer connection
    // pc.current.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate))

    candidates.current.forEach((candidate) => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(candidate));
      pc.current.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
    });
  };

  const remoteVideo = remoteStream ? (
    <RTCView
      key={2}
      mirror={true}
      style={{ ...styles.rtcViewRemote }}
      objectFit="contain"
      streamURL={remoteStream && remoteStream.toURL()}
    />
  ) : (
    <View style={{ padding: 15 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 22, textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
        Waiting for Peer connection ...
      </Text>
    </View>
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="blue" barStyle={"dark-content"} />
      <View style={{ ...styles.buttonsContainer }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={createOffer}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={{ ...styles.textContent }}>Call</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={createAnswer}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
              <Text style={{ ...styles.textContent }}>Answer</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ ...styles.videosContainer }}>
        <View
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            zIndex: 1,
            bottom: 10,
            right: 10,
            width: 100,
            height: 200,
            backgroundColor: "black", //width: '100%', height: '100%'
          }}
        >
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => localStream._tracks[1]._switchCamera()}
            >
              <View>
                <RTCView
                  key={1}
                  zOrder={0}
                  objectFit="cover"
                  style={{ ...styles.rtcView }}
                  streamURL={localStream && localStream.toURL()}
                />
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <ScrollView style={{ ...styles.scrollView }}>
          <View
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              width: "100%",
              backgroundColor: "black",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >
            {remoteVideo}
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonsContainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
  },
  button: {
    margin: 5,
    paddingVertical: 10,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  textContent: {
    fontFamily: "Avenir",
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  videosContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  rtcView: {
    width: 100, //dimensions.width,
    height: 200, //dimensions.height / 2,
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
  scrollView: {
    flex: 1,
    // flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: "teal",
    padding: 15,
  },
  rtcViewRemote: {
    width: dimensions.width - 30,
    height: 200, //dimensions.height / 2,
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
});
```

Comment: hi thanks your solution works in react native but the same dont work in react  any idea on why it is different in react ? @kartikey

Comment: i have updated my question with react js code in the end @Kartikey